# Upload new version of app with new project iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, app-store

Well, I have submitted an app to the app store, but i have lost my laptop :( there were no backup of my code so i lost it, now i want to update my app.

So now i have to rebuilt everything back to how it was by creating a new project,

So i want to know, what are the compulsory things i need to have ? for uploading a new version of app to app store like **BUNDLE ID, App name etc**

***Please help and thanks for giving me your valuable time in reading.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same appID and provisioning profile. This should not be a problem since you must be having access to the developer account. Following are the list of items:

- bundleID
- distribution certificate(need to revoke the existing one)
- provisioning profile(need to create new one after revoking the certificate)
- keys for any third party APIs like GA, TesFlight, Facebook etc, which u should be able to   get easily if have access to the corresponding accounts

The following link guides you how to revoke existing certificates

[Revoking Existing Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW26)

Comment: Older distribution certificates will no longer be valid if the 'private keys' were not backed up from old mac. Old Certificates must be revoked to regenerate new ones

Comment: where to check for private keys ? can i get it from apple dev acc ?

Comment: @Krunal check the link in my answer

Comment: Will i able to see my no of downloads for old version ? in itunesconnect ? if i create new certificates.

Comment: creating new certificates won't affect your app which is already in appstore. So, yes you will be able to see no of downloads

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use exact same bundle ID in your new app. Then it will be linked to your existing app in your iTunes Connect.

Since you lost your laptop ,assuming you don't have any 'private keys' backed up with you, You need to 'Revoke' your certificates with using new lap top and regenerate provisioning profiles. Your older provisioning profiles will not work in your new Mac unless you don't have previous private keys. So revoking solves this problem.

Comment: where to check for private keys ? in apple dev acc ? if don't get it from there then are you sure generating new certificates will solve my problem ?

Comment: private keys are located in the 'KeyChain Access' of the Mac you have used to originally create certificates. If you don't have access to that Mac, only option is Revoking. You will create new private keys along the process, and they will be stored in Keychain access of that new Mac.